# use PHP to create an HTML table from a MSQL query, without duplicate rows?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm creating a display for a student module webpage that displays in this format

**2001/02**

- Computer Science
- Biology
- Lorem Ipsum

**2002/03**

- Subject
- Subject
- Subject

In that style
The data base I'm using contains information such as

- year(2001/02)
- credit(10)
- mods.mid(CS500)
- mtitle(module title - software engineering, biology, chemistry...etc)

the PHP code I have displays every module title, so literally I giant list of modules whereas I want to split it out like up there described, Years displayed THEN every module for that year. Any one people help me? Code down below:

```
<?php
echo "<table cellspacing='40'>";
$query2 ="SELECT  mods.mid, ayr, mtitle, credits FROM stud, smod, mods WHERE stud.sid = '".$_POST['stuNo']."' and stud.sid = smod.sid and smod.mid = mods.mid order by ayr ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

echo "Enrolment and progress";
echo "<table width='150' border='1'>";

echo "<th> Module Selection</th>"; 
echo"<td>".$row["ayr"]."</td>";


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $temp_year=$row["ayr"];
echo "<tr>";


 if ($temp_year!=$row["ayr"]){
     echo "<td>" . $row["ayr"] . "</td>";
 }

echo "<td>" . $row["mid"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["mtitle"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["credits"] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I wouldn't know how to seperate it by year, any help is great. thank you.

Comment: can't you just sort by year?

Comment: @Dagon its not the sorting part, its the displaying the year for the modules in the specific way thats described

Comment: Loop-keep the year in a local variable, when the year  changes, your loop stats a new year\data display

Comment: @Dagon ill give that a try now, thank you.

Comment: `$temp_year=$row["ayr"]` ... `(if $temp_year!=$row["ayr"]){//new year)` ...

Comment: @Dagon this some what works, it just displays the year of the modules, It doesn't output it as a want :( such as 
Year:
module
module

Comment: update the code, and ill tweak it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably code it like this, probably not the only way but should work based on what I believe you are trying to achieve. Please make sure to add the "order by" to your SQL query as well.

```
echo "<table cellspacing='40'>";
$query2 = "SELECT mods.mid, ayr, mtitle, credits FROM stud, smod, mods WHERE stud.sid = '".$_POST['stuNo']."' and stud.sid = smod.sid and smod.mid = mods.mid ORDER BY ayr DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

echo "Enrollment and Progress";
echo "<table width='150' border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td colspan="3"><b>Module Selection</b></td></tr>";
$year = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($year != $row["ayr"]) {
       echo "<tr><td colspan="3"><b>" . $row["ayr"] . "</b></td></tr>";
       $year = $row["ayr"];
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["mid"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["mtitle"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["credits"] . "</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! THANK YOU!

Comment: or some one can just write it for you.